# How to transfer DOM data from one window to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a jQuery/Javascript function by which data from multiple `div`s on a webpage is used to fill out a form on an adjacent window or tab in Chrome.

I am able to capture the data but is there a method to access other tabs or would I have to create a Chrome extension?

Comment: If you don't control both pages then yes, you will need an extension. If you DO control both, there may be other ways (`postMessage` comes to mind)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on whether you have control over both pages.

1. If you don't control the receiving page, then the only way to access its DOM would be through a Chrome extension injecting a [Content Script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). It would be able to access the page's form to fill it out, and communicate with other tabs e.g. via the background page.

   If you wish to try developing such an extension, I *highly* recommend reading through the [Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) page carefully.
2. In case you do control the pages in question, it's a bit of a weird goal, but achievable.

   - Suppose the pages are on the same domain. Then they share `localStorage`/`sessionStorage`, and a [`change` event](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html#storage-event) will fire in one if you modify it in another.
   - If they are not in the same domain but you control them both, you can look into using [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) to transfer data.

Please note though: your question says "transfer DOM data". All of the solutions above will only transport [JSON-serializable](http://www.json.org/) data (or strings). Some DOM-related data, like `HTMLElement`s themselves, cannot be fully serialized.